# Revit API: Direction of rebar spacing (Python)

Tags: revit-api

I'm trying to multiply rebar in a slab using following methods:

(using Python script)

```
doc = DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentDBDocument
RS = Autodesk.Revit.DB.Structure
RebarType = MyRebarType
slab = MySlab
norm = XYZ(0,0,1)
bar = MyCurve
n = MyQuantity
s2 = RebarSpacing
hook_type = None

rebar = RS.Rebar.CreateFromCurves(doc,RS.RebarStyle.Standard,RebarType,hook_type,hook_type,slab,norm,bar,RS.RebarHookOrientation.Right,RS.RebarHookOrientation.Left,True,True)
rebar.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.REBAR_ELEM_LAYOUT_RULE).Set(3)
rebar.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.REBAR_ELEM_QUANTITY_OF_BARS).Set(n)
rebar.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.REBAR_ELEM_BAR_SPACING).Set(s2)
```

The problem is that i cant define direction of my rebar spacing. It depends on rebar position in my slab.
[Here is an example of how this code creates rebars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UIOe.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to add one line:
rebar.GetShapeDrivenAccessor().BarsOnNormalSide = True